# custom yaml files not being seen in symfony

Tags: symfony1, yaml

I created a custom yaml handler, myRunnerConfigHandler, and placed it under

apps/frontend/lib/myRunnerConfigHandler.class.php

and created a new config_handler and placed it under

apps/frontend/config/config_handler.yml

Now, under config_handler.yml,I placed my configuration for my new rundown:

```
modules/*/config/rundown.yml:
    class: myRundownConfigHandler
```

Basically, under each module, I want to have a yaml file under 
    /apps/frontend/modules/home/config/rundown.yml

However no rundown.yml files are being seen.  Is there something else I need to do before rundown.ymls are seen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Naming-issues? myRunnerConfigHandler VS myRundownConfigHandler ? I see you have them both in your example.